How can I view the performance of my Vanguard account over the last day?
On Schwab, I can follow Accounts > Portfolio Performance, then select a particular account and date range (with particular start and end dates!) to see the percent return on that account on a particular day. Is this possible on Vanguard's website? As far as I can tell, it shows the percent returns for the past day of individual holdings, but does not show the total percent returns of an account for a particular day. I can also follow Portfolio > Performance > Custom Date Range, and then select a range, but here I am limited to only selecting start and end months. Am I missing something?

Edit: Also, the Holdings page does not show results for an account overall:


For the last day you can find it on the "Holdings" page (see your previous question - that's what you were asking about).
For other days, Vanguard doesn't directly give such an option.
Historical daily movements are generally not a useful information. That said, there is an option to fetch positions and balances on any given day within the last 24 months, and with that you can do the math yourself. You can get that on the "balances by date" page.

As far as I can tell, the "Holdings" page does not show this for the entire account -- see my added screenshot. As far as usefulness, it's helpful to answer the question, "What will happen if this day repeats for two weeks?"

@BetterthanKwora as I said, not a very useful piece of information, but you have all the raw data available to you to do that math. Vanguard, as a brokerage, is not interested in day-traders. Their target clientele is long term investors.
